# How To Make ul Take up Remaining Height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `ul` which is nested inside many layers of `div`s. I would like my `ul`'s height to be as big as it can without causing the screen size to be bigger than the window. bellow is a sample markup of my HTML.

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
    ...
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6>
        <ul>
        ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Setting the `ul` height to `100%` does not work.

Comment: The percentage height of an element is referring to the percentage of the parent container. You will need to ensure that all parent containers are also 100%

Comment: You can also define a `position: absolute`. There are a few ways to do what you want, please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link  u can use top and botton property for this

http://24ways.org/2008/absolute-columns/